# Limited Permissions to a domain user on AD Server

Tags: active-directory, permissions

How to assign permissions to a domanin user such that he can only change active directry users password & he can be able to join or remove Client computers to the domain.

He should have admin rights on all (Client computers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question 1:

> - Log on to Windows Server as a domain administrator and open Server Manager from the icon on the desktop Taskbar or from the Start screen.
> - Select Active Directory Users and Computers (ADUC) from the Tools menu.
> - In the left pane of ADUC, expand your domain, right-click the Users container (or the OU for which you want to delegate permissions)
>     and select Delegate Control from the menu.
> - Click Next on the welcome screen.
> - On the Users or Groups screen, click Add.
> - In the Select Users, Computers, or Groups dialog, type the name of the AD group you want to give permission to reset user account
>     passwords and click OK. In this example, I already have an AD group
>     called HelpDesk that I’m going to use.
> - On the Users or Groups screen, click Next.
> - On the Tasks to Delegate screen, check Reset user passwords and force password change at next logon and click Next.

Question 2 :

> Delegate rights using Active Directory Users and Computers:
>
> 1. Open the Active Directory Users and Computers
>
> snap-in.
>
> 2. Right-click the container under which you want the computers added, and press Delegate Control.
> 3. Press Next.
> 4. Press Add.
> 5. After adding all the users and/or groups, press Next.
> 6. Select Create custom task to delegate and press Next.
> 7. Select Only the following objects in the folder, check Computer objects, check the Create selected objects in this folder box, and
>      press Next.
> 8. Check the Create all child object box and press Next.
> 9. Press Finish.

Question 3

> Start by creating a new GPO named Restricted Groups: GROUP NAME (ex:
>   Restricted Groups: Local Administrators). Edit the GPO and navigate to
>   Computer Configuration/Policies/Windows Settings/Security
>   Settings/Restricted Groups.  Under Group Name, right click and select
>   Add Group.

Comment: Unable to login remotely to dc after even assigning RDP permissions.

Comment: @Ranveer You install the RSAT tool to the user who want to manage the user. To RDP to a DC you need more right and it's not a good practice  (https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=7887)

Comment: Thanx for your quick responce